# Real world sample of Financial accounting data models

Tags: database-design, schema, financial, accounting

i am going to develop financial accounting software. But i am not experienced at accounting software data models.

if anyone has real world samples of data models of financial accounting software, 
please share.

thanks.

Comment: You will want to ask a specific question to get a decent answer on this site.  As it stands, your post is far too vague, and has a good chance of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

Martin Fowler's book "Analysis patterns" is more about object oriented design than databases, but you should read it anyway - he has sections on how to treat time, currency and financial transactions that you need to know about.

The "Data model resource book" by Silverston has a good section on modelling financial data.

Finally, if you want "real world" examples, you may have to grab some open source projects related to your particular requirements, and see how they store the data.

Answer (score 1):

Each design starts with business requirements gathering and analysis, then follows the application model and then you start thinking bout the database.

Real life data models of financial accounting systems are way to big to share here.